# Disrespectful wheel mouse zooming in CartoDB

Tags: carto, zoom, mouse-wheel

When building a vizualization in CartoDB, I have the option to "Allow wheel mouse zooming" but it seems not to respect it in the output map.  Any idea why not?

Answer (score 2):

When you use CartoDB Editor, you need to activate the option called **Scroll wheel zoom**. Then, you could use this feature in an **Embed map** (Share -> Embed it (or Get a simple URL).

[image]

If you're using [CartoDB.js](https://github.com/cartodb/cartodb.js) , please verify that you don't have the option **scrollwheel** disabled when you're [instantiating your map](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js.html#arguments).